# How to install google chrome on android 3.0 emulator?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Well from last couple of weeks I am developing an application using html, javascript on android emulator3.0
which I am running on my desktop(Windows XP).To run my programs I use webkit browser which I think default one for the android emulator and it is showing many problems to support HTML and Javascript objects and properties.

So I was assuming that may be if I install google chrome on the emulator then it can give me a desktop like behavior on the emulator.May be my assumption is wrong.i am very new in this field.

So anyone have any idea that whether it is possible or not?If it is possible then how I can do this.

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Regards,

Arvind Thakur

Comment: You can't. Chrome is a browser made for desktop OS, not for Android. The stock browser of Android is based on WebKit just as Chrome is.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747312/install-chrome-for-android-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google chrome is not available for Android (at least yet) [link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=413a6889f7ac3fe2&hl=en)

Maybe you can try to install Firefox or Opera, both of them should have a version for Android

Answer (score 0):

There is article on How to get Google Play, that would let to install other apps, including Google Chrome for Android

Installing Google Play on Android Emulator May 2nd, 2012
http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html