# Is Google Play Store supported in avd emulators?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-virtual-device

After googling quite a bit I am unable to find the answer to this question. Is google play store officially support in avd emulators.

I know it was once stopped , then I hear that it was brought back after specific version of android. I am using avd android version 4.4.3 (api 19) google app . I dont see a google play store app there. Am I suppose to expect it? Or is there an official apk for google play store that can be installed on the avd officially?

Comment: You can always download the APK and install via ADB

Comment: Anyone knows the reason for why it's disabled in the first place?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Starting from Android Studio 2.3.2
 now you can create an AVD that has Play Store pre-installed on it. Currently, it is supported on the AVD's running

- A device definition of Nexus 5 or 5X phone, or any Android Wear
- A system image since Android 7.0 (API 24)

[Official Source](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html)

For other emulators, you can try the solution mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581874/m).

Comment: on MacOS, Android studio 3.1, Emulator Nexus 5X, Android 7.0 or 8.0 doesn't have Play Store :(

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question. Look below for Jamal Eason's answer.

Answer (score 240):

The Google Play Store is now officially preinstalled the Android Emulator. Make sure you are running the latest version of Android Studio 2.4. In the Android Studio AVD Manager choose a virtual device configuration that has the Google Play store icon next to it, and then select one of the system images that have the label "Google Play". See this release note: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html

[image: Android Studio AVD Manager with Google Play Store support]

Comment: I appears to be available in 2.3.3 also.  But only for two phone images, no tablets yet.  I suppose you can choose the phone and then tweak it into a tablet format.  My 2.3.3 screen is identical to the one shown here.

Comment: For me avd manager required to pick nexus device to get play store. For instance, Pixel devices did not have option to choose google play system image, but only google apis.

Comment: When I tried this, trying to open the Play Store just got stuck on "Checking Info" screen. Haven't found a workaround yet.

Comment: It didn't work with an existing avd, but it does with a new one as of 6/2018: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#google_play_store_on_pixel_device_images

Comment: Deb's answer helped me most. Without first loading a "Google Play" enabled system image no Google Play enabled AVD could be created. I also noticed that only for a few devices a Googla Play enabled image is available.

Answer (score 182):

**Easiest way:**
You should create a new emulator, and before opening it for the first time, follow these easy steps:

1. Locate the directory where the emulator has been created. For example, in Windows go to:
   **"%userprofile%.android\avd"** and open your virtual device folder.
2. Open file **config.ini** with a text editor like Notepad.
3. Locate **PlayStore.enabled** key and change its value to true:

   PlayStore.enabled = true
4. Ensure Play Store images is installed in the SDK manager. Read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/just-push-play-using-google-play-android-emulator/) for more information.
5. Locate **image.sysdir.1** entry and change:
   `google_apis` to `google_apis_playstore`. Example:

   ```
   image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\
   ```

   to

   ```
   image.sysdir.1 = system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
   ```

Comment: Currently the best way to have a tablet emulator with Google Play.

Comment: After changing these settings, am I supposed to launch the emulator from the AVD manager? I'm getting an error "The emulator process for AVD ... was killled"

Comment: As I mentioned; you have to create a "New" emulator, don't open it, and do the changes, then you can open it.

Comment: Where can I find the file to change ? I have a mac.

Comment: @Learn2Code open AVD manager, right click device, then select "Show on Disk"

Comment: You can use an "already used" avd, just click in "wipe data"

Comment: thank you @SharifYazdian
this worked for me.
I was working on a crash that had happened on a Tab and on my emulator the tab does not have google play, I was unable to debug because location services did not work.
With this process the emulator now has google play and can access google play services.

Comment: In my case there was no need to create a new AVD, it worked using an existing one. Just in _Settings..._ > _SDK Platforms_ I had to install the corresponding **Google Play ... System Image**. Then I modified the config.ini as mentioned, and _Cold Boot Now_.

Comment: Make sure you have the google play store system image downloaded aswell.

Comment: Piggy backing off @HimmetAvsar Its best to go into the settings and fully install the version of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you. This was it. Wanted to tie together the comments from @saltandpepper and Salvador: If you're getting "The emulator didn't start up" (or some similar error), choose Cold Boot from the device's menu.

Comment: image.sysdir.1 entry - where is this supposed to be? I'm not seeing it in the .ini file

Comment: It bewilders me why those settings are not set by default.

Answer (score 47):

When creating AVD...

1. Pick a device with google play icon.

   [image: Select Device Screen]
2. Pick the google play version of the image, of your desired API level.

   [image: Select System Image]
3. Now, after creating the AVD, you should see the google play icon.

   [image: Virtual Devices]

Comment: With Android Studio Giraffe when pick a device with that option I'm unable to select an OS image on the next screen.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you can enable/use Play Store on Android Emulator(AVD):
Before that you have to set up some prerequisites:

1. Start **Android SDK Manager** and select **Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image** (Recomended: *because it will work comparatively faster*) of your required android version (For Example: *Android 7.1.1 or API 25*)

> [Note: *Please keep all other thing as it is, if you are going to
>   install it for first time*] 
>   Or Install as the image below:
>   [image]

2. After download is complete Goto **Tools**->**Manage AVDs...**->**Create** from your Android SDK Manager
3. [image]

Check you have provided following option correctly. Not sure about internal and SD card storage. You can choose different. And Target must be your downloaded android version

4. Also check **Google Play Intel Atom (x86)** in CPU/ABI is provided
5. Click **OK**
6. Then **Start** your Android Emulator. There you will see the Android Play Store. See ---
   [image]

Comment: I can neither find *Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image* in SDK Manager nor *Google Play Intel Atom (x86)* in CPU/ABI section when creating emulator.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu in the right bottom corner there is a switch "Show Package Details" click on it, and you will see it

Comment: thanks this worked, But i noticed that my previous emulator also had the same configurations (Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image & Android 7.1.1 ). But it didn't have playstore

Answer (score 29):

When you create a virtual device from Android Studio pay attention to the Play Store Column in the device table. The images with the play store icon have google play pre-installed.

> ❗️ *In system images that come with google play root is not available.*

[image: android studio images with playstore]

After you've created the AVD you'll also be able to see from the Android Studio AVD Manager which of your images have google play installed:

[image]

Comment: Not for tablets though. Shame

Comment: @MacaronLover: then, for example, you could use genymotion which is free for personal use and where you can install gapps by clicking in the top right corner icon in the emulator window. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su

Comment: Thanks for the visual @ccpizza

Answer (score 12):

on the `Select a Device` option choose a device with `google play icon` and then select a system image that shows `Google play` in the target

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no google play store in avd emulator. But you can install it manually.

1. Install Google APIs System Image, so you will have google services already (without play store)
2. Create AVD based on Google APIs image
3. Download smallest archive from http://opengapps.org/ and extract Phonesky.apk from it
4. Push Phonesky.apk to /system/priv-app/ on avd.
5. Restart avd. Google play should be there.

Recently I've just tried to do it by myself and you can find detailed tutorial on my blog: http://linuxoidchannel.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-install-google-play-store-on.html

Comment: Did you get "Device incompatible" warnings on the apps in the Play Store? About 90% of them are incompatible on mine. I can't really install anything I need (Firefox/Opera)

Comment: The play store is available on a subset of images

Comment: After pushing Phonesky.apk and restarting emulator my emulator is not powering on.

Comment: This is worked for Nexus_5_API_28.  `/` was the mount point for `system`. Therefore used `mount -o rw,remount /dev/root /`

Comment: @gavsiu any resolution to this? Can't seem to download an app we are testing that has been confirmed available on a minimum of Android 4.4 (API 19) and targets the latest Android 9.0 (API 28). How to know if app and why it is "incompatible" if our emulated device supports Google Play store and is running an Android 8.0?

Comment: @jtth: Does [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/06/find-out-why-apps-are-incompatible-with-your-android-device/) help you? If not, please post a new question, and please provide me with a link to the question.

Comment: @Sergey this answer is no longer correct, you can install google play now in some emulators.

Answer (score 3):

If using the command line, you'll need to use one of the packages listed with

```
sdkmanager --list | grep "playstore"
```

Once that is installed you can use the appropriate package in

```
avdmanager create avd --force --name testAVD --abi google_apis_playstore/x86_64 --package "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64" -d 19
```

Replace `google_apis_playstore;x86_64` with the package you installed

Comment: I found the grep for playstore to be critical. I had version 26 revision 14 installed but that did not contain playstore. I need to install version 26 revision 7 and I only found that by using these instructions.

Answer (score -4):

<del>It's not officially supported yet.</del>

**Edit:**  It's now supported in modern versions of Android Studio, at least on some platforms.

#### Old workarounds

If you're using an old version of Android Studio which doesn't support the Google Play Store, and you refuse to upgrade, here are two possible workarounds:

1. Ask your favorite app's maintainers to upload a copy of their app into the [Amazon Appstore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Appstore).  Next, install the Appstore onto your Android device.  Finally, use the Appstore to install your favorite app.
2. Or:  Do a Web search to find a .apk file for the software you want.  For example, if you want to install SleepBot in your Android emulator, you can do a Google Web search for [ `SleepBot apk` ].  Then use `adb install` to install the .apk file.