# How can I install Google Play on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I tried this method: "[Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)"
 but terminal gives me this error

**'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I am using Android Studio 2.2 and there isn't Play Store column or installing Play Store choice.

So how can I install Google Play and apk files on my emulator?

Comment: google play are u asking about play store or play services? if you want emulator with play services you can create emulator from android studio which comes with it

Comment: I want to install Play Store.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593738/is-google-play-store-supported-in-avd-emulators android studio version must be 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you can create an AVD that has Play Store pre-installed on it.

Check the image, now you have a column with this information.
[image]

Comment: there isn't Play Store column bro

Comment: make sure your Android Studio is at 2.4 as minimum