# Android emulator: Installing google play services on tablet emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

How can I install Google play services on android emulator tablet. I know Nexus 5 and Nexus 5X comes with play services installed. I need to test my app on tablet emulator.

Comment: Anyone can help ?

Comment: Late answer, but this could help the new ones. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62680014/2713403