# Why Does `expo client:install:android` Fail to Install Expo Go on Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, expo, command-line-interface, expo-go

I'm trying to install Expo Go on my emulator using the command `expo client:install:android`, but while the emulator opens, the app never installs and the command eventually times out.

[image]

I'm using a fresh project created using the command `expo init Test0_Blank` and I've cd'd into my project's directory. According to the documentation I've found, running `expo client:install:android` should install Expo Go at this point but it doesn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is likely because you have never actually logged into the Google Play Store (or App Store, for iOS) on your emulator / simulator. The command tries to download the app from the store, and it can't because your account there hasn't been enabled yet. Log into the store on your emulator/simulator and then try running the command again --- it should work this time!

Comment: how do you "Log into the store on your emulator/simulator" ?

Comment: Make sure your emulator has Google Play Services enabled (see here if not sure how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593738). Then open the Google Play app. It will prompt you to log in using your google credentials. Log in (don't need to add a credit card or anything). After that, it should work.

Comment: thanks. it took me a long time to realize only some images support Play Store.